# Segmentation fault when trying to print strings from 2D array via array of pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

#### Edit:

So, for anyone having the same problem, it seems that despite initializing the array of pointers to NULL, the array still had some trash written in it. I fixed the segmentation by replacing the header of the last while statement(in function printer) with this:

```
while( (wordPtr[ctr] != NULL) && (ctr < MAX_WORDS) )
```

#### Original question:

The first function of the program is supposed to get some text and populate a two-dimensional array of strings with the words in the text, but each word has to appear only once. Then, it has to populate a two-dimensional array of pointers to strings with the addresses of the words in such a way that the second function can then use those pointers to reprint the text in the order it was originally.

The problem I am facing is that, while the array of strings seems to populate as it should, I face a segmentation fault error whenever I try to print the text using the array of pointers.

I think that the problem lies somewhere in the lines where I direct the pointer to the word, but other than that I can't find much.

I tried using gdb, but the result pointed to strlen.s, which is a function that I haven't used anywhere in the code.

Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_WORDS 6
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 10

void placer(char wordsArray[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN], char *ptr[MAX_WORDS][2]);
void printer(char *wordPtr[][2], int linelen);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
     char wordArray[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN] = {{ '\0' }};
     char *wordPtr[MAX_WORDS][2] = {{ NULL }};
     int linelen = 100;
     
     placer(wordArray, wordPtr); 
     printer(wordPtr, linelen);
     
     return 0;
}

void placer(char wordsArray[][MAX_WORD_LEN], char *ptr[][2]){
    
    int i, j, k, temp, w = 0, g = 0;
    char check[MAX_WORD_LEN] = {'\0'};
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) {
        
        scanf("%s", wordsArray[i]);
        
        //Converts to lowercase
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_WORD_LEN; j++) {
            if(isupper(wordsArray[i][j])) {
                wordsArray[i][j] = tolower(wordsArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        //assigns to pointer array
        ptr[w][0] = &wordsArray[i][0];
        
        //Checks if word already exists in array
        for(k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            if(strcmp(wordsArray[i], wordsArray[k]) == 0) {
                //Directs pointer to the already existing instance of the word
                ptr[w][0] = &wordsArray[k][0];
                //replaces the word with \0
                for (g = 0; g < MAX_WORD_LEN; g++) {
                    wordsArray[i][g] = '\0';
                }
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
        w++;
    }
    
    //prints from array of unique words
    printf("%s\n\n\n", &wordsArray[1][0]);
    for(temp = 0; temp < MAX_WORDS; temp++) {
        printf("%s\n", wordsArray[temp]);
    }
    
    printf("\n##\n");
}

void printer(char *wordPtr[][2], int linelen) {
    
    int ctr = 0, t;
        
    //prints using pointers
    while (wordPtr[ctr] != NULL) {
        printf("%s", *wordPtr[ctr]);
        ctr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no reason for `ptr` in *any* of this code. If the goal is to continually prompt for, and read, strings until `MAX_WORDS` unique words have been accumulated, the 2D pointer arrays in this source seem pointless.

Comment: It might be that this issue is caused by that you trying to use `strcmp()`at certain array elements during the loop. `for(k = 0; k < i; k++) {if(strcmp(wordsArray[i], wordsArray[k]) == 0) {}`

Comment: to WhozCraig, this program has more functions later on and is homework, so I don't have much room for changes in code. It's basically all laid out in a way.

Comment: To RobertS, what could you suggest as a way to replace strcmp?

Comment: @mltsd Not to replace it, but to leave the array index numbers out of the game. Or does it fulfill a certain purpose? But as i said i´m not sure if this is causing this issue in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent opportunity to learn to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger).  Your system almost surely provides a way to run the code in a way so you can single-step through the source code, view the value of variables at any point, place breakpoints, etc.

By doing so you can check what the program *actually* does versus what you expected it to do.  Most problems of this type are very easily diagnosed by single stepping.  Each debugger has (at least) a small learning curve but it is well worth the effort to learn the basics.